# How validate two password fields by ajax?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, passwords, validation

I'm trying to validate two password fields with JSF but no good until  now, I search for it on google but everything was about JSF 1.2 and pretty confusing, I'm using JSF 2.0.

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password"  value="#{register.user.password}"  >  
            <f:ajax    event="blur"   listener="#{register.validatePassword}" render="m_password" />
        </h:inputSecret>
        <rich:message id="m_password" for="password"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="password_2" value="Password (again):" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password_2"  value="#{register.user.password_2}"  >  
            <f:ajax    event="blur"     listener="#{register.validatePassword}" />
        </h:inputSecret>
```

This is how I it is my controller:

```
public void validatePassword() {
    FacesMessage message;

    if (!user.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword_2()) ){
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "different password");
    }else{
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, null, "ok");
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form:password", message);
}
```

Any idea guys ?

Comment: What do you mean it is working but not so good? Is it slow? Not sure I understand what you want to change and why.

Comment: Hi @jdias, I mean is not working the way it suppose to be. Thanks for that could be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, use a *real* [`Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html) to validate the input. Don't do it in an action event method.

As to your concrete problem, you just need to specify the *both* fields in the `execute` attribute of the `<f:ajax>`, it namely defaults to the current component only. If you attach a validator to the first input and send the the value of the second input along as a `<f:attribute>`, then you will be able to grab it in the validator. You can use the `binding` attribute to bind the component to the view. This way you can pass its submitted value along by [`UIInput#getSubmittedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#getSubmittedValue%28%29).

Here's a kickoff example:

```html
<h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{bean.password}" required="true">
    <f:validator validatorId="confirmPasswordValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="confirm" value="#{confirmPassword.submittedValue}" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="password confirm" render="m_password" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message id="m_password" for="password" />

<h:outputLabel for="confirm" value="Password (again):" />
<h:inputSecret id="confirm" binding="#{confirmPassword}" required="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="password confirm" render="m_password m_confirm" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message id="m_confirm" for="confirm" />
```

*(note that I added `required="true"` to both components and also note that you don't necessarily need to bind the confirm password component value to a managed bean property, it's worthless over there anyway)*

with this validator

```java
@FacesValidator("confirmPasswordValidator")
public class ConfirmPasswordValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String password = (String) value;
        String confirm = (String) component.getAttributes().get("confirm");

        if (password == null || confirm == null) {
            return; // Just ignore and let required="true" do its job.
        }

        if (!password.equals(confirm)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Passwords are not equal."));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what's confirmPassword in binding="#{confirmPassword}" ?

Comment: @Jsword: it will bind the component to the view by exactly the given identifier so that it's available by `#{confirmPassword}` elsewhere in the view (such as in `<f:attribute>` of the first field so that it can be obtained in validator).

Comment: I understand now the function of 'binding' BalusC, thanks for the help dude.

Comment: You're welcome. You can by the way also bind it to a bean property. It would then be an `UIInput` property. But that's not necessary in this case (and it would break viewscoped beans).

Answer (score 0):

With seam 2 you have the component `<s:validateEquality>` and you don't need to write code. For JSF2 then you have Seam 3 modules, particulary [Faces module](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule) and Cross-field Form Validation. An example :

First you have to use the **`s:validateForm`** tag:

```
<h:form id="passwordForm">
    <h:inputSecret id="newPassword"
        required="true"
        redisplay="true"
        value="#{passwordController.newPassword}">
    </h:inputSecret>            
    <h:inputSecret id="confirmationPassword"
        value="#{passwordController.confirmPassword}"
        required="true"
        redisplay="true">
    </h:inputSecret>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{passwordController.submitPassword}" />
    <s:validateForm validatorId="passwordValidator" />
</h:form>
```

and the corresponding Validator for the password form above would look like this:

```
@FacesValidator("PasswordValidator")
public class PasswordValidator implements Validator
{
   @Inject
   @InputField
   private String newPassword;

   @Inject
   @InputField
   private String confirmPassword;

   @Override
   public void validate(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent comp, final Object values) throws ValidatorException
   {
      if (!confirmPassword.equals(newPassword))
      {
         throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Passwords do not match!"));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I looked for a similar solution in pure JSF2, but I couldn't find it. Do you know if this exists in JSF2? Especially the @InputField annotation seems useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) p:password tag. Please see demo [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/password.jsf). It has **match** attribute which should be the id of confirm password.

```
<p:panel header="Match Mode">  
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>  

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid">                     
                <h:outputLabel for="pass" value="Password " />  
                <p:password id="pass" value="#{passwordBean.password}" match="confirmPass"   required="true"/>  

                <h:outputLabel for="confirmPass" value="Confirm Password " />  
                <p:password id="confirmPass" value="#{passwordBean.confirmPassword}" required="true"/>  
    </h:panelGrid>  

    <p:commandButton id="saveButton" update="matchGrid" value="Save" />  
</p:panel>
```