# Why can I not get the submitted value from component binding?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, validation

In register.xhtml page, I have 2 `inputText` components for password and confirm password as following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

   <h:form>

      <h:outputText style="font-weight: bold" value="Password: " />
      <p:password feedback="true" minLength="9" 
                  binding="#{mrBean.passwordComponent}"
                  id="password" value="#{mrBean.password}"/>
      <p:message for="password" id="passwordMsg" />

      <h:outputText style="font-weight: bold" value="Confirm password: " />
      <p:password feedback="false" minLength="9" 
                  id="confirmPassword" value="#{mrBean.confirmPassword}"
                  validator="#{mrBean.validateConfirmPassword}>
         <f:attribute name="oriPassword" value="#{mrBean.passwordComponent.submittedValue}"/>
         <p:ajax process="password confirmPassword" update="confirmPasswordMsg" /> 
      </p:password>
      <p:message for="confirmPassword" id="confirmPasswordMsg" />

   </h:form>

</html>
```

And this is my mrBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {

    private String  password;
    private String  confirmPassword;
    private UIInput passwordComponent;

    public void validateConfirmPassword(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        String passwordStr        = (String) toValidate.getAttributes().get("oriPassword");
        String confirmPasswordStr = (String) value;

        if (!confirmPasswordStr.equals(passwordStr)) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("The 2 passwords do not match.");
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }

}
```

In another page, I also have a similar bean with similar validate function for email & confirmEmail and it works perfectly. However, I have no idea why it couldn't work here. The `passwordStr` is always `null` even though I have already entered the password.

I'd be very grateful if someone could show me what I have done wrong here.

Best regards,
James Tran

Comment: Perhaps the validator method should be `validateConfirmPassword` and not `validateConfirmEmail`. Have you posted the right code?

Comment: @VineetReynolds: Thanks for correcting me :P. I typed the code wrongly. I have updated my question with the proper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF components are processed in the order they appear in the component tree. During validations phase, for each component the submitted value will be retrieved by `getSubmittedValue()`, converted and validated. If no exceptions occurred during conversion and validation, then the submitted value will be set to `null` and the converted and validated value will be set as local value by `setValue()`.

You're trying to reference the submitted value of the component which has **already** been processed at that point. The submitted value will only be non-`null` when conversion/validation failed for that value. You need to reference its local value instead.

```html
<f:attribute name="oriPassword" value="#{mrBean.passwordComponent.value}"/>
```

#### See also:

- [How validate two password fields by ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489893/how-validate-two-password-fields-by-ajax/7493527#7493527) (this example does the other way round, so that you don't need an additional property for confirm password)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is perfect as always =).