# PrimeFaces selectOneMenu have null new value in both valueChangeListener and ajax listener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

I've got a problem with PrimeFaces. Here is my XHTML code :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{gCnewObjectBean.grille.branche}"
    valueChangeListener="#{gCnewObjectBean.brancheChangedListener}"
    update=":contentform :popup">
    <f:selectItems value="#{gCnewObjectBean.branche}" />
    <p:ajax update=":contentform :popup"
        listener="#{gCnewObjectBean.brancheChangedListener}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And here is my bean code :

```
public void brancheChangedListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Integer branche = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
    // do populate the second select menu based on this value
}
public void brancheChangedListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    SelectOneMenu selectMenu = (SelectOneMenu) event.getSource();
    Integer branche = (Integer) selectMenu.getSubmittedValue();
    // do populate the second select menu based on this value
}
```

The HTML code generated is a bit strange with primefaces, the HTML select component is hidden. But if I see it with firebug, it looks like this :

```
<select id="branche_input" name="branche_input">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Prestations prévoyance professionnelle</option>
    <option value="2">Prestations prévoyance privée</option>
    <option value="3">Prestations PRIRENT</option>
    <option value="4">Gestion prévoyance professionnelle</option>
</select>
```

This code is a way to test the two solutions (`valueChangeListener` and the `f:ajax`) described by BalusC on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/).

When I do change the value in the select menu, both listener are triggered, first the `valueChangeEvent`, then the `AjaxBehaviorEvent`, which is perfectly what I suspected based on BalusC post. But both bean method do get a "null" for the new value (with debugger, I can see that the old value in the `ValueChangeEvent` is "0", which is correct according to my selectItems).

Any clue to solve this ? I really dont get it, I saw the code I'm using several time on this site...

Technical info : JBoss EAP 6.0, Mojarra 2.1.7-jboss, PrimeFaces 4.0

Edit : I was wondering if it was a bug in the jsf-impl library embedded in JBoss. I updated to Mojarra 2.1.18-jboss, but the problem is strictly the same : a `null` value is placed into my `grille` object by the ajax listener and a `null` value is also returned by the `getNewValue()` object of the `valueChangeEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i think there is a problem with your f:selectItems tag. Try to set the itemValue and itemLabel attributes for it: (I think the gCnewObjectBean.branche is not a integerList,is it?)

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{gCnewObjectBean.grille.branche}"
   valueChangeListener="#{gCnewObjectBean.brancheChangedListener}"
   update=":contentform :popup">
   <f:selectItems value="#{gCnewObjectBean.brancheList}" var="item" 
       itemValue="#{item.branche}" itemLabel="#{item.label}"/>
   <p:ajax update=":contentform :popup"
    listener="#{gCnewObjectBean.brancheChangedListener}" />
```

Your attempt to get the selected value with the getSubmittedValue() method can't work. getSubmittedValue is not returning the value you are expecting:

See  [Why can I not get the submitted value from component binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366846/why-can-i-not-get-the-submitted-value-from-component-binding)

If this is not the solution to your problem, you can try to put a p:messages tag in your jsf page. Probably there are errors which does not show up in the console.

Comment: There was two different problems in my code, one was not visible with the code I provided. You were right about the `getSubmittedValue()`, it is indeed always `null` because the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` is triggered after the update model values phase. I have to retrieve the selected id directly from my model. As of my `selectItems`, that wasn't a problem because my `getBranche()` method had this signature : `public List<SelectItem> getBranche() {`

Comment: The second part of the problem was that my `p:dialog` was NOT in any form in the page. For some reasons, I had to put my `p:confirmDialog` out of any form. I thought I should do the same for the `dialog`, which was indeed a bad idea. Out of a form, no values are submitted to the server. This part was not visible from the code I provided.