# How to show one error message for all components wrapped in a composite component

Tags: jsf

everyone. I have few composite components on my page and after validation failed each of them adds it's own validation message in the .
I found needed ability in 17.4 of the http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/web.1111/e28163/af_message.htm maybe somebody knows a way to make it with Primefaces?

Thanks in advance!(-:

Comment: You can use [***p:messages***](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml) tag to show combined messages for all validation failed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link an error message to multiple UIComponent in JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616086/link-an-error-message-to-multiple-uicomponent-in-jsf2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few solutions for this problem.

1. That one which discribed in  [Link an error message to multiple UIComponent in JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616086/link-an-error-message-to-multiple-uicomponent-in-jsf2) but it doesn't work for me, becouse I have six of the same composite components.
2. Same idea with validation on the last component but with using of

   `<h:inputHidden id=''datecheck" validator="#{bb.validateSomeThing}"value="needed"/>`

   that should to be placed after all components.
3. My solution is

   `<h:panelGrid id="example">
       <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{testBean.inputValidation}"/>
       <p:column>
           <my:compositeComponent param1="#{x.a[0]}" param2="#{y]}" update="#{something}" readonly="#{not editAccess}"/>
       </p:column>
   <p:column>
           <my:compositeComponent param1="#{x.a[1]}" param2="#{y]}" update="#{something}" readonly="#{not editAccess}"/>
       </p:column>
   <p:column>
           <my:compositeComponent param1="#{x.a[2]}" param2="#{y]}" update="#{something}" readonly="#{not editAccess}"/>
       </p:column>
       ...
   </h:panelGrid>`

For more information I recommend to read [Core JavaServer Faces (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012896)

7th chapter **Validation Relationships Between Multiple Components** and 8th chapter **Multi-Component Validation** could be useful.