# How can I display ValidatorException and required="true" of same input field in different messages elements

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I took the following [BalusC kickoff example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493527/617373) and modified it a bit by adding a submit button and additional h:messages and removing the `f:ajax` from the `h:inputSecret's` (removed the `f:ajax` cause for some reason when I leave the first `h:inputSecret` it immediately displays "value is required" error for the second `h:inputSecret` - but the user haven't got the chance to type it in... ???  <- another future question ?:) )

**OK, to make long story short:**

I'm trying to figure out how can display the validation errors regarding the both password fields(that the passwords are not equal) in the global h:messages and not in the individual h:message of the password fields
I do want that the required="true" will be displayed in the `<h:message` of each field...

But right now the validation message (thrown by my exception) and the required="true" are being displayed in the same place

Here is the code:

```
<h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{bean.password}" required="true">
    <f:validator validatorId="confirmPasswordValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="confirm" value="#{confirmPassword.submittedValue}" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message id="m_password" for="password" />

<h:outputLabel for="confirm" value="Password (again):" />
<h:inputSecret id="confirm" binding="#{confirmPassword}" required="true">
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message id="m_confirm" for="confirm" />
```

And additional `h:commandButton` with `h:messages` below that code :

```
<h:commandButton value="doSomething" action="#{myBean.myAction}">
    <f:ajax execute="password confirm" render="m_password m_confirm"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
<h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="validation_value_required"/>
```

```java
@FacesValidator("confirmPasswordValidator")
public class ConfirmPasswordValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String password = (String) value;
        String confirm = (String) component.getAttributes().get("confirm");

        if (password == null || confirm == null) {
            return; // Just ignore and let required="true" do its job.
        }

        if (!password.equals(confirm)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Passwords are not equal."));
        }
    }

}
```

Also

Thanks ahead,

**Solution (Thanks to BalusC)**

changed

```
<f:attribute name="confirm" value="#{confirmPassword.submittedValue}" />
```

to

```
<f:attribute name="confirm" value="#{confirmPassword}" />
```

and

```
String confirm = (String) component.getAttributes().get("confirm");
```

into

```
UIInput confirmPasswordComponent = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("confirm");
String confirm = (String) confirmPasswordComponent.getSubmittedValue();
```

and

```
throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Passwords are not equal."));
```

into

```
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Passwords are not equal."));
context.validationFailed();
((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
confirmPasswordComponent.setValid(false);
return;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a `Validator` on a particular component throws a `ValidatorException`, then its `FacesMessage` will automatically be associated with the component on which the `Validator` is invoked.

You need to manually add the `FacesMessage` on a `null` client ID so that it end up in `<h:messages globalOnly="true">`. You also need to manually set `validationFailed()` on `FacesContext` so that JSF won't update the model values nor invoke the action. If necessary (though recommended), you also need to manually mark the components as invalid so that any appropriate listeners/tree-visitors (e.g. for highlighting) will take this into account.

```
if (!password.equals(confirm)) {
    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Passwords are not equal."));
    context.validationFailed();
    ((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
    confirmPasswordComponent.setValid(false); // You'd need to pass it as component instead of as its submitted value in f:attribute.
}
```

By the way, the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) project has an `<o:validateEqual>` component which should make this less tedious. See also [showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual).

Comment: You'd need to pass it as component instead of as its submitted value in f:attribute. How?